# How to get back the index after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the the record with maximum value from the first record in each group after groupby and delete the same from the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                   'cost': [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5]})
print df 
t = df.groupby('item_id').first() #lost track of the index
desired_row = t[t.cost == t.cost.max()]
#delete this row from df

         cost
item_id      
d           5
```

I need to keep track of `desired_row` and delete this row from `df` and repeat the process.

What is the best way to find and delete the `desired_row`?

Comment: try using df.drop API [DataFrame.drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: How can I know which index to drop from `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'cost': [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5]})
t=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id'],keep='first')
desired_row = t[t.cost == t.cost.max()]
df[~df.index.isin([desired_row.index[0]])]

Out[186]: 
   cost item_id
0     1       a
1     2       a
2     1       b
3     1       b
4     3       b
5     1       c
```

Comment: converting last row to `df[~df.index.isin([desired_row.index[0]])]` will work for me.

Comment: @leaner edited ~ ,IDK which one you prefer to keep in order to filter and updated

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure of a general way, but this will work in your case since you are taking the first item of each group (it would also easily work on the last).  In fact, because of the general nature of split-aggregate-combine, I don't think this is easily achievable without doing it yourself.

```
gb = df.groupby('item_id', as_index=False)
>>> gb.groups  # Index locations of each group.
{'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': [5], 'd': [6]}

# Get the first index location from each group using a dictionary comprehension.
subset = {k: v[0] for k, v in gb.groups.iteritems()}
df2 = df.iloc[subset.values()]
# These are the first items in each groupby.
>>> df2
   cost item_id
0     1       a
5     1       c
2     1       b
6     5       d

# Exclude any items from above where the cost is equal to the max cost across the first item in each group.
>>> df[~df.index.isin(df2[df2.cost == df2.cost.max()].index)]
   cost item_id
0     1       a
1     2       a
2     1       b
3     1       b
4     3       b
5     1       c
```

Comment: Thanks but it will delete all rows that has `d` in `item_id` column.  I onlywant to drop the row which has max `cost`

Answer (score 1):

Or using not in

Consider this df with few more rows

```
pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd','d'], 
               'cost': [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5,1,7]})

df[~df.cost.isin(df.groupby('item_id').first().max().tolist())]

    cost    item_id
0   1       a
1   2       a
2   1       b
3   1       b
4   3       b
5   1       c
7   1       d
8   7       d
```

Comment: This solution doesn't delete all the cost corresponding to 'd'. pl see the edit

Comment: It doesn't work with this df: `df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd','d'], 
               'cost': [5, 2, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5,1,7]})`  because you are deleting all rows where the cost is equal to the max cost of the *first* item.

Comment: @Alexander, I am sorry but I don't get you. The output dataframe that I have posted only has one row less at index 6. Unless I have understood the question wrong

Comment: @learner, what would be the expected behavior if there are two rows with max value. Say the cost at index 0 is also 5?

Comment: @Vaishali I need to drop only one row. Deleting all rows is not viable for me.

Comment: The solution I posted with isin drops only 1 row as you can see in the output dataframe

Comment: I think, it wouldn't work for this example: `df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd','d'],
               'cost': [7, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 7,1,5]})`

Comment: This has two instances of max(7), one for ID a and other for d. Which max would you want deleted in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Overview: Create a dataframe using an dictionary. Group by item_id and find the max value. enumerate over the grouped dataframe and use the key which is an numeric value to return the alpha index value.  Create an result_df dataframe if you desire.

```
   df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
               'cost': [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5]})

   grouped=df_temp.groupby(['item_id'])['cost'].max()

   result_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['item_id','cost'])

   for key, value in enumerate(grouped):
     index=grouped.index[key]
     result_df=result_df.append({'item_id':index,'cost':value},ignore_index=True)

   print(result_df.head(5))
```